# add line between axis to divide axis chart .net report

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2008, charts

I have chart in report as follows:

[image]

I just wanted to add vertical line on x-axis labels to show them separately as below:

[image]

Plz help me, through which option i can obtain this?